# How to keep data from notifications while Android application is in background or closed

Tags: java, android, firebase, notifications

I need help. As I wrote in title , I don't know how to keep data from notification when it arrives and the application is in background or killed. What i need to pass ( code below) is a Plate that i need for an elaboration . Here is the code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
   String text= remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    SharedPreferences s = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Functions.putStringInPrefs(s, Constants.PREFS_ALERT_PLATE, text);


    if (Functions.isUserSignedUp(this)) {

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "Message Title:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());

            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            try {
                sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    }
}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FragmentChangeActivity.class);
    String prova = notification.getBody();



    intent.putExtra("alert_plate" , prova);
    GlobalData.alertPlate=prova; // object used as cache
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    if(notification.getTitle()!= null){
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.details_icon).setContentTitle(notification.getTitle());

    } else{
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.details_icon).setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    }

    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.details_icon).setContentText(notification.getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt((100000000 - 1) + 1) + 1, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.details_icon).build());



   }


}
```

What do I need to change ? Thank you !
Ps. In manifest the class is declared in the correct way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of FCM messages

1) Notification message
2) Data message

So if you want to receive data when the app is close you have to send your data using data message. Your data format will be something look like below

```
{
    "to": "device_id",
    "data": {
        "param_1": "vale 1",
        "param_2": "value 2",
        "param_3": "Value 3"
    }
}
```

After receiving the message now you can store your data in shared preference or database whatever you want.